# Why casting result of Select to List returns null

Tags: c#, linq, list, distinct, var

Why my method GetList() returns null after a linq statement?

```
public static List<MyType> GetListOfAllLocations()
{
    var DistinctList = ListWith25Elements.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(y => y.First());

    return DistinctList as List<MyType>
}
```

...

```
foreach(MyType mt in GetListOfAllLocations())... // this is null?!?!
```

Comment: is `typeof(IEnumerable<MyType>) == typeof(List<MyType)`?

Comment: What is `ListWith25Elements`? What are the objects it contains?

Answer (score 6):

`DistinctList` is an `IEnumerable<MyType>`, to get it as a `List<MyType>` you have to do

```
return DistinctList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have to use a list in this case at all. However if you need to load the values eagerly (either because you need to enumerate them several times, or because you are in a SQL context...) you will have to do:

```
var distinctList = listWith25Elements.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(y => y.First());

return distinctList.ToList()
```